# I'm getting a 404 error when migrating wordpress site from one PC wamp to another PC wamp?

Tags: wordpress, error-handling, migration, http-status-code-404

I am getting 404 error, after migrated wordpress site from one PC wamp to another PC wamp?

Comment: Did you update all siteurl in database?

Comment: my site URL not change.
Its same in both PC, Like this : http://localhost/tc/
But new location Home page open but other pages URL not work.

Comment: Please update wp-admin Settings -> Permalink with default

Answer (score 1):

### Edit wp-config.php

Add these two lines to your `wp-config.php`, where **"example.com"** is the correct location of your site.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

### Update permalink

**Step 1 :** Goto `wp-admin->setting->permalinks`

**Steps 2 :** After save changes

[image]

Comment: check echo 'test'; in your new localhost/wp/index.php file and check is it printing or not?

Comment: @GunvantParmar have you updated your permalink setting?

Answer (score 1):

This could be that your WordPress site on your new local environment need some changes, and there are some steps to follow: [Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

2 obvious changes:

- Have you updated your `wp_options` table?
- Have you updated your `wp-config.php` file with the new database credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Settings > Permalinks and changing the permalink structure to Plain. If the pages work after that, you can change the permalink structure back to whatever you wish.

I've had it before where just re-saving the same permalink setting doesn't resolve the 404's, but changing it to Plain does.